# why my for loop doesn't take the input which i put it in?

Tags: r

Below is the input of the code I have written I am trying to obtain results from the list X to add to the player's score. I am attempting to use a for loop to achieve this.
Input:

```
X<-c("run5", "run0", "run0", "run5", "out", "illegal")
playerA=list(name="T Smith","run0"=0,"run1"=0,"run2"=0,"run3"=0,"run5"=0,illegal=0,Out=0,Tol=0)
    for (X in playerA) {
    
playerA[["run0"]]<-playerA[["run0"]]+1
    } 
print(playerA)
```

output:

```
$run0
[1] 9
```

The output returns 9 Run0's when there are only two in the list.
Am I on the right track? or is there another function to perform this more efficiently?

edit:
"What exactly are you doing?"

So here is a list of overs which I am trying to sort in R

```
gameOvers <- list(c("run5", "run0", "run5", "run5", "out", "illegal"),
                  c("out", "out", "run1", "illegal", "run2", "run5"),
                  c("illegal", "run1", "run2", "run2", "run2", "out"),
                  c("out", "run5", "run0", "run2", "out", "run0"),
                  c("illegal", "run0", "run5", "illegal", "out", "run2"),
                  c("run2", "run5", "out", "run1", "run2", "out"))
```

and here is a list of the players

```
players <- list(
    initialisePlayer("T Smith"),
    initialisePlayer("B Border"),
    initialisePlayer("S Ponting")
```

what I am attempting to do is when the nominated players are batting/bowling for that specific over, I want to add the scores to the appropriate part of their score sheet and generate a total. A correct score sheet would like similar to this:

```
Name         0s  1s  2s  3s  5s   X Out Tot
T Smith       1   3   2   4   2   4   0  25
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing? You are looping over the entire list, and each time you add 1 ro run0, so this is expected.

Comment: I guess you want something like `lapply(X, \(x) playerA[[x]] <<- playerA[[x]] + 1)` ?

Comment: You have hard-coded `[["run0"]]` inside your `for` loop, why not use `[[X]]` instead?